# How to add hyperlinks to a CSV export

Tags: php, csv, export

I need to export a csv file. In that export file i need a link for the text.

Example:(demo.doc) i need link for that "demo.doc".

Is that possible?

Comment: is that what you wanted to ask? How to exports hyperlinks inside a csv file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSV file has no concept of hyperlinks:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: I need to export a csv file in that export file i need a link for the text. eg(demo.doc) i need link for that "demo.doc". Is that possible

Comment: @Mohanraj please re read my answer and think link provided.